# Karaf webbundle not able to find persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I have written a karaf web bundle(wab). I have kept persistence.xml in META-INF/persistence.xml as well as tried putting in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

when i try to create an EntityManagerFactory i am getting the below error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named CustomXML
```

So in case of a karaf wab where should the persistence.xml reside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a

```
Meta-Persistence: \
    META-INF/persistence.xml
```

To the MANIFEST.MF file.